# Excel 2003 “SHIFT+Copy” functionality - where is it in 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel

i  use the 2003 "SHIFT+Copy" function very frequently - eg every monthly. I have thus far been unable to find it anywhere in 2010 and have spent about 10 minutes searching MS on line.

Does anyone have the solution of "SHIFT+Copy - as PRINTED"?

Comment: did JMax answer this as you wanted or are you looking for a shortcut key sequence as you have used before?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

- Select Range
- At Home tab > Clipboard Group > Click Arrow button on Paste button Choose As Picture > Copy as Picture
- Choose option on copy picture.
- At Home tab > Clipboard Group > click Arrow button on Paste button Choose As Picture > Paste as Picture

Is that what you were looking for ?

Regards,

Max

Comment: Yeah, pretty much all your copy and past commands are gonna be under the paste icon.